# What is the name of this symbol that looks like a double crucifix?

Tags: image-identification

I found this symbol in the movie "*The Day of the Jackal (1973)*" opening scenes.

[image: cross with two horizontal bars, the upper one shorter than the lower]

What is it called in English?

Comment: It is also a typographical symbol called the double dagger: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with English.

Comment: @Lambie - I doubt it refers to a doble dagger, anyway that would have a more recent origin compared to the original cross. The Day of the Jackal " A professional assassin codenamed "Jackal" plots to kill Charles de Gaulle, the President of France. .... ***The Cross of Lorraine, a symbol General Charles de Gaulle used during his lifetime***.

Comment: @Josh Perhaps not but a double dagger is about English whereas the Cross of Lorraine is about the French. :)

Comment: @tchrist In what way it is **off-topic** even **image identification** exist here?

Comment: @DhanrajKumar I didn't invent the tag. Figure out what the picture is of in your own language, then translate that to English.

Comment: @tchrist I am satisfied with **Josh** answer & accepted it. no worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the ***[Cross of Lorraine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_of_Lorraine)***:

> - ***The Cross of Lorraine (French: Croix de Lorraine) was originally a heraldic cross.***  The two-barred cross consists of a vertical line crossed by two shorter horizontal bars.
> - ***In most renditions, the horizontal bars are "graded" with the upper bar being the shorter, though variations with the bars of equal length are also seen.*** The Lorraine name has come to signify several cross variations, including the patriarchal cross with its bars near the top.

Origin:

> - The Cross of Lorraine came from the Kingdom of Hungary to the Duchy of Lorraine. In Hungary, Béla III was the first monarch to use the two-barred cross as the symbol of royal power in the late 12th century. He probably adopted it from the Byzantine Empire, according to historian Pál Engel.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: It was used to crucify those rare persons who were born with an extra set of arms.